# acquireTokenByClientCredentials in @azure/msal-react?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-react, react-aad-msal

In msal-node, By `ConfidentialClientApplication` and `acquireTokenByClientCredintial` API I was able to authenticate successfully and get the token without specifying user login detials. I want the same functionality in my React app using msal-react. Able to get token by `acquireTokenSilent` api and providing user details. Unable to find a proper documentation or sample code how to generate token without user login.

Is there any way to authenticate by client credentials without user login in msal-react ??

Comment: Currently msal-react only supports public application. We need to use backend which is capable of keeping those secret. So, Created a Http Trigger function in azure, authenticated using client credentials, and get the token from there in my React app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClientCredential Auth flow is designed for  Confidential Client applications. msal-react is an auth library which supports only SPA type of apps which are public client applications, hence there is no support for ClientCredential flow in the library.

Comment: If you can expand on what your use case is, we can help with the appropriate auth pattern you may want to follow. Feel free to drop a question in our github channel: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js

Comment: Thanks @sameerag. I posted the issue and here is the link. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5714.

LMK, if you understand my requirement